# Eclipse / Jframe - Unable to Launch

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

When I click on run/debug in eclipse, it gives me this error:

Title:Unable to Launch
"The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches"

Here is my code:

```
package jframe1;
import javax.swing.*;
public class jframe1 {
    public static void main(String args){
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     JButton button = new JButton("clikity");

     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     frame.getContentPane().add(button);

     frame.setSize(300, 300);
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It runs fine if I make a command line application, but not when I start using JFrame I cannot run my code/application.

How do I fix this? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse can't find your `main` function as you have declared it wrongly.
Change `.. main(String args)` to `.. main(String [] args)` and it will work!

**Code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class jframe1 {

    // It's String[] args
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("clikity");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void main(String args){
```

should be

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
```

Comment: Thank you!, very much appreciated, my bad I didn't even notice.